# How do I link different users to view the page differently?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm working on how different group of users will be able to view different buttons, but i cant seem to make that work;
my elif doesn't work, when i'm logged in to employee i'm able to view the buttons but when im logged in the inventory manager i can only view undefined user

[image: employee view]

[image: inventory manager view]

below are my codes
views.py

```
def menu(request):
    user = request.user
    is_employee = request.user.groups.filter(name='employee').exists()
    is_inventorymanager = user.groups.filter(name='inventorymanager').exists()
    is_financialdirector = user.groups.filter(name='financialdirector').exists()
    is_vendor = user.groups.filter(name='vendor').exists()
    return render(request, 'app/menu.html', {
        'is_employee': is_employee,
        'is_inventorymanager': is_inventorymanager,
        'is_financialdirector': is_financialdirector,
        'is_vendor': is_vendor
    })
```

menu.html (interface)

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div>
    <br />

    {% if is_employee %}
         <h2>Employee Menu</h2>

    {% elif is_inventorymanager %}
         <h2>Inventory Manager Menu</h2>

    {% elif is_financialdirector %}
         <h2>Financial Director Menu</h2>

    {% elif is_vendor %}
         <h2>Vendor Menu</h2> 

    {% else %} 
        <h2>Undefined</h2>    

    {% endif %}
    <br />


    <table>
    {% if is_employee %}

        <tr><td>
    <form class="margintop" action='createpurchaseorder' method='GET'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"> EMP | Create Purchase Order</button><br />  
    </form>
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td>
    <form class="margintop" action='createdeliveryorder' method='GET'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"> VEN | Create Delivery Order</button><br />
    </form>
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td>
    <form class="margintop" action='listview_po' method='GET'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">EMP FM VEND | View Purchase Orders</button><br />
    </form>
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td>
    <form class="margintop" action='listview_do' method='GET'>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">IM VEN | View Delivery Orders </button><br />
    </form>
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td>
    <form class="margintop" action='list_po' method='GET'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">FD | Verify Purchase Orders</button><br />
    </form>
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td>
    <form class="margintop" action='list_do' method='GET'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">IM | Verify Delivery Orders</button><br />
    </form>
        </td></tr>


        <tr><td>
    <form class="margintop" action='viewpurchaseorder' method='GET'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect">(Bug) Search Purchase Order</button><br />
    </form>
        </td></tr>

        
    {% elif is_inventorymanager %}            
        <tr><td>
    <form class="margintop" action='verifydeliveryorder' method='GET'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Verify Delivery Order</button><br />
    </form>
        </td></tr>
            
        <tr><td>
    <form class="margintop" action='viewdeliveryorder' method='GET'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect">View Delivery Order</button><br />
    </form>
        </td></tr>    
   
        <tr><td>
    <form class="margintop" action='createpurchaseorder' method='GET'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Create Purchase Order</button><br />  
    </form>
        </td></tr>        
        
    {% elif is_financialdirector %}
        <tr><td>
    <form class="margintop" action='verifypurchaseorder' method='GET'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Verify Purchase Order</button><br />
    </form>
        </td></tr>
            
        <tr><td>
    <form class="margintop" action='viewpurchaseorder' method='GET'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect">View Purchase Order</button><br />  
    </form>
        </td></tr>

    {% elif is_vendor %}            
        <tr><td>
    <form class="margintop" action='viewpurchaseorder' method='GET'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect">View Purchase Order</button><br />
    </form>
        </td></tr>
            
        <tr><td>
    <form class="margintop" action='viewdeliveryorder' method='GET'>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect">View Delivery Order</button><br />
    </form>
        </td></tr>       

    {% else %}            

        <tr><td>
            <p>Undefined User.</p>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            
    {% endif %}            
    </table>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you share your models?

Comment: I feel like shown code is fine. Probably the problem lays within adding the group to the user. Maybe you can show that part of your code. Apart from that: maybe you could just add a `print(user.groups)` somewhere, just to confirm that the user is for sure part of that group.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have an option to make user a member of different groups. it means if user is `employee` and `inventory manager` - thats fine

### If it suppose to be like that:

then you will display different menus in one template

### IF it's not:

I suggest to you, use the another field for user, something like:

```py
class UserRoles(models.IntegerChoices):
    EMPLOYEE = 1, "Employee"
    INVENTORY_MANAGER = 2, "Inventory manager"
    ...

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ...

    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=UserRoles.choices, default=UserRoles.employee)
    ...
```

then you can define the const with templates:

```py
MENU_TEMPLATE_PER_USER_ROLE = {
    UserRoles.EMPLOYEE: "templates/employee_menu.html",
    UserRoles.INVENTORY_MANAGER: "templates/inventory_manager_menu.html",
    ...
}
```

and use this in views when u choose the templates

```py
def menu(request):
    template = MENU_TEMPLATE_PER_USER_ROLE.get(request.user.role, default="templates/default_menu.html")
    return render(request, template)
```

Comment: If you need just change the name of group in templates, you can just send to context `{"role": request.user.get_role_display()"}` and then inside templates just display this `role` variable's value